# Remove certain String from array php

Tags: php, mysql, split

I want to get rid of that string with help of the `str_replace` function in `PHP` but I won't work. Can anybody help me?

```
$sql = "SELECT data from users";
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  $widgets = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $widgets[] = $row;
}

$alignment = explode("//",serialize($widgets));

for($i = 0; $i<count($alignment); $i++){
  str_replace("a:3:{i:0,:a:2:{:i:0;s:31;q}")
}

  ?>
```

Comment: `str_replace` needs at least 3 parameters.

Comment: specify which part you want to replace with which string...

Comment: Why are you trying to `explode` a serialized PHP string, and why are you then trying to replace part of it? You shouldn't ever be applying string operations to the output of `serialize` - that's a really bad sign.

Comment: I'm quite new in developing php, so what would you suggest instead of serialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

php_replace take 3 arguments

```
$replaced = str_replace(search, replaced_by, initial_string, [&replaced]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function for clarity, and change your code like below:

```
$replacedValue = str_replace("a:3:{i:0,:a:2:{:i:0;s:31;q}","",$alignment[$i]);
```

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work for me, because it said "uninitialized string offset"